# Programmatically delete files in Data Lake Storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am importing data into an Azure Data Lake and using Data Lake Analytics to convert it from JSON format to CSV using U-SQL. After converting I want to delete the JSON formatted data. It seems that you cannot delete files using U-SQL.

I was wondering what the best way is to schedule a task that will run every 24 hours and will delete all data that has already been converted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a good feature request. You might want to try to add it here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake if you do please post a link so others can upvote if they come across your post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use powershell and azure automation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell

I think the this should get you started:

```
Remove-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName $dataLakeStoreName -Paths $myrootdir\mynewdirectory\vehicle1_09142014.csv, $myrootdir\mynewdirectoryvehicle1_09142014_Copy.csv
```

Here is some more info on powershell with ADL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-powershell

You could also use a batch job from azure data factory or perhaps even a simple webhook from a logic app lots of options.